# Mongoose and Android Volley

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, android-volley

I am trying to communicate Android Client (using volley ) with express (node.js) server (Server is also using mongoose).  Android Code for request is

```
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/tasks/";

 CustomRequest myRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.i("ApP CreateActivity","Response Secussfully" );


                    Log.i("ApP CreateActivity", "HTTP REPONCE RECIEVED " + response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject myCreditentials = response.getJSONObject(0);
                        Log.i("ApP CreateActivity", "SECUSSFUL LOGIN");

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("ApP CreateActivity", "JSON EXCEPTION");
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("ApP CreateActivity", "Error While Fetch Response --> network Error");



                }
            });

            myRequest.setTag("createtask");
            queue.add(myRequest);
```

Now On the server side there are two different codes.

```
version-1
    router.post('/tasks/', function(req, res, next) {
    Task.find(function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log('------------------------------');
    console.log('Find Works');
    console.log('------------------------------');
    res.json(todos);
  });
version-2
router.post('/tasks/', function(req, res, next) {
    var myTask = new Task();
    // initialization --> myTask...
    myTask.save( function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json( todos );
    console.log('------------------------------');
    console.log('Create WOrks');
    console.log('------------------------------');
  });
```

Now problem is 
Android --> version-1(find task)  WORKS FINE. i.e. Android logs show "SUCCESSFUL LOGIN"
Android --> version-2(Create Task) gives Error i.e. onErrorResponce gets called . Logs show "Error While Fetch Responce".

Server output version-1 : Fetch Works . (expected output).
Server output version-2 : Create Works. (Data is added into db correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue , If you print the error passed in errorResponce function it will show that its a JSON parsing error (version-2) rather then some networking error.Actually the response is expected to be JSON-ARRAY but instead it receives a JSON-OBJECT. But it is an error therefore the error-listener is called.
   So I changed the response from JSON-OBJECT to JSON-ARRAY and problem is fixed.

```
     myTask.save( function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    var myTaskArray = [];
    myTaskArray.push(todos);
    res.json( myTaskArray );
    console.log('------------------------------');
    console.log('Something WOrks');
    console.log('------------------------------');    
  });
```

This works.